# Azure AD connect custom install

Tags: active-directory, sql-server, entra-id

I am trying to install Azure AD connect to sync the on-premise AD with Azure. I thought the whole process would be simple enough. However, I am facing strange issue. I have created service account, which has all rights needed to work with Azure AD (it is basically a domain admin). I want to use full install of SQL Server instead of Express. Thus, I am choosing custom install and getting a red line without any text (it seems to be an error, but with no text). I am stuck at this point. Do you know what have I missed? 
Thanks!

Comment: Try reviewing one of the xxx_install.log files at `C:\Users\yourName\appdata\local\aadconnect` for the actual error text. Start with `AADConnector_Install.log` there are also a few others. Then edit your post with the error text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"First of all login to the server where you installing Azure AD connect with **an account you have created**. It should help. Also, check the article below it describes similar error: [Fighting Azure AD Connects custom installer | StarWind Blog](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/fighting-azure-ad-connects-custom-installer)"

Comment: Thanks! The article was really helpful. I have successfully installed AD connect